# Getting Error in This Test Class

Tags: apex, trigger, failing-tests, future, httprequest

```
         @isTest
    private class LeadUpdateTriggerHandlerTest {
        @isTest
        static void testHandleUpdate() {
            // Create test data
            Lead testLead = new Lead(FirstName = 'Test', LastName = 'Lead', Company = 'Test Company');
            insert testLead;

        // Simulate updated data
        Map<String, Object> updatedData = new Map<String, Object>();
        updatedData.put('Id', testLead.Id);
        updatedData.put('FirstName', 'Updated First Name');
        updatedData.put('LastName', 'Updated Last Name');
        updatedData.put('Company', 'Updated Company');

        List<Map<String, Object>> updatedDataList = new List<Map<String, Object>>();
        updatedDataList.add(updatedData);

        // Convert the updated data to JSON
        String updatedDataJson = JSON.serialize(updatedDataList);

        // Create a mock implementation of the HttpCalloutMock interface
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockHttpResponseGenerator());

        // Call the handleUpdate method (replace 'LeadUpdateTriggerHandler' with the actual class name)
        Test.startTest();
        LeadApiTriggerHelper.handleUpdate(updatedDataJson);
        Test.stopTest();

        // Perform assertions or verifications as needed
        // Verify the expected behavior of the handleUpdate method
    }

    @isTest
    static void testProcessLead() {
        // Create test data
        Lead testLead = new Lead(FirstName = 'Test', LastName = 'Lead', Company = 'Test Company');
        insert testLead;

        // Simulate updated data
        Map<String, Object> updatedData = new Map<String, Object>();
        updatedData.put('Id', testLead.Id);
        updatedData.put('FirstName', 'Updated First Name');
        updatedData.put('LastName', 'Updated Last Name');
        updatedData.put('Company', 'Updated Company');

        List<Map<String, Object>> updatedDataList = new List<Map<String, Object>>();
        updatedDataList.add(updatedData);

        // Convert the updated data to JSON
        String updatedDataJson = JSON.serialize(updatedDataList);

        // Create a mock implementation of the HttpCalloutMock interface
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockHttpResponseGenerator());

        // Call the processLead method (replace 'LeadUpdateTriggerHandler' with the actual class name)
        Test.startTest();
        LeadApiTriggerHelper.processLead(new List<Lead>{testLead}, new Map<Id, Lead>{testLead.Id => testLead});
        Test.stopTest();

        // Perform assertions or verifications as needed
        // Verify the expected behavior of the processLead method
    }

    @isTest
    static void testCreateUpdatedData() {
        // Create test data
        Lead testLead = new Lead(FirstName = 'Test', LastName = 'Lead', Company = 'Test Company');

        // Get the Lead object describe information
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult leadDescribe = Lead.SObjectType.getDescribe();
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldsMap = leadDescribe.fields.getMap();

        // Call the createUpdatedData method (replace 'LeadUpdateTriggerHandler' with the actual class name)
        Map<String, Object> updatedData = LeadApiTriggerHelper.createUpdatedData(testLead, fieldsMap);

        // Perform assertions or verifications
        //System.assertEquals(testLead.FirstName, updatedData.get('FirstName'));
        //System.assertEquals(testLead.LastName, updatedData.get('LastName'));
        //System.assertEquals(testLead.Company, updatedData.get('Company'));
        // Add more assertions for other fields as needed
    }

    // Helper class for mocking HTTP callout responses
    private class MockHttpResponseGenerator implements HttpCalloutMock {
        public HttpResponse respond(HttpRequest request){
            // Create a mock HTTP response
            HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse();
            response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            response.setBody('{"success": true}');
            response.setStatusCode(200);
            return response;
        }
    }
 @isTest
    static void testHandleAfterInsert() {
        // Create test data
        Lead testLead1 = new Lead(FirstName = 'Test', LastName = 'Lead1', Company = 'Test Company', Flag__c = true);
        Lead testLead2 = new Lead(FirstName = 'Test', LastName = 'Lead2', Company = 'Test Company', Flag__c = false);

        List<Lead> newLeads = new List<Lead>{testLead1, testLead2};
        insert newLeads;

        // Call the handleAfterInsert method
        Test.startTest();
        LeadConversionTriggerHandler.handleAfterInsert(newLeads);
        Test.stopTest();

        // Perform assertions or verifications as needed
        // Verify the expected behavior after inserting leads
    }

    @isTest
    static void testHandleAfterUpdate() {
        // Create test data
        Lead testLead1 = new Lead(FirstName = 'Test', LastName = 'Lead1', Company = 'Test Company', Flag__c = true);
        Lead testLead2 = new Lead(FirstName = 'Test', LastName = 'Lead2', Company = 'Test Company', Flag__c = false);

        List<Lead> newLeads = new List<Lead>{testLead1, testLead2};
        insert newLeads;

        testLead1.Flag__c = false;
        testLead2.Flag__c = true;

        update newLeads;

        // Call the handleAfterUpdate method
        Test.startTest();
        LeadConversionTriggerHandler.handleAfterUpdate(newLeads, new Map<Id, Lead>{testLead1.Id => testLead1, testLead2.Id => testLead2});
        Test.stopTest();

        // Perform assertions or verifications as needed
        // Verify the expected behavior after updating leads
    }
    

     

    // Add more test methods for other handler methods and scenarios as needed
}
```

Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts

In the First Methods I am sending JSON data by HTTP Callouts for Lead when a lead is created or Updated and in Last two methods I am converting lead when it's coming through API when the Flag__c is true

Comment: Which test method is giving you the error?

Comment: testHandleAfterInsert and testHandleAfterUpdate
@fred

Comment: Does `LeadConversionTriggerHandler.handleAfterUpdate` do any callouts?

Comment: NO it doesn't have any callout its just lead conversion Trigger In which lead converting on giveen condition at the time of creation and Updation but  LeadApiTriggerHelper Have  Callouts @fred

Comment: Which line is causing the error? Do you have a full stack trace you can share?

Comment: I Created one trigger and In that Trigger i called Two Helper classes in one class i am makeing HTTP callouts and in other i am converting lead

Comment: Which line is causing the error: Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts?

Comment: I check the logs 
Class.LeadApiTriggerHelper.sendUpdatedData: line 110, column 1
Class.LeadApiTriggerHelper.handleUpdate: line 13, column 1

Comment: 18:03:31.194 (2325692593)|FATAL_ERROR|System.TypeException: Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error means that you're testing a method which makes a callout. To do that you need to add a mock.

Add `Test.setMock` to your other test methods like you have done in the first two.